# Error calling ETPush.getInstance().addTag( ); on Android SDK Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush-android

Error:

```
Process: com.cmr.activities.debug, PID: 18161
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.cmr.activities.CMRApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush$a.d()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4641)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush$a.d()' on a null object reference
        at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush.getInstance(SourceFile:163)
        at com.cmr.activities.CMRApplication.onCreate(CMRApplication.java:56)
```

Comment: Are you using Proguard?  It looks like you have not included the necessary Proguard rule for the SDK.

Comment: Nop, it's a debug release, without proguard

Comment: What version of the SDK and what flags did you pass into ReadyAimFire()?

Comment: Hey I am Facing the same issue can you please confirm that did you found any solution to it. Thanks